# would it be a good design to deploy a Spring batch application using AWS Batch service?

Tags: amazon-ec2, spring-batch, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I am doing a POC for batch application which is expected to be deployed in AWS cloud.

This batch is application is heavy expected to compute huge calculation for 2m-10M of records monthly. So number of EC2 instances has to grow dynamically based on the load.

Actually I was thinking of creating a spring-batch application that will be deployed in AWS ECS service.

However I see new AWS-Batch service which is also helping to deploy the job.

My question is can I deploy my spring-batch application using AWS-Batch assuming my batch application is containerized using docker. is it a good approach or should I go with deploying in ECS? Please suggest.

Thanks,
Mani.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have given, **AWS Batch seems to be ideal for your application.**

In general, ECS should rather be used for hosting services, while AWS Batch does computation. Also, AWS Batch is actually built on top of ECS for providing the functionality your application is likely to need. It also works well with Spot instances and will therefore save you money.

Further resources:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/9syduu/how_does_aws_ecs_differ_from_aws_batch/
- [How is a batch processing system in AWS ECS different from AWS Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50665234/how-is-a-batch-processing-system-in-aws-ecs-different-from-aws-batch)

Comment: Thank you thomas for the reply.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for the reply.                                                                                                          

As I told I am planing to create spring-batch application where the source file will be partitioned using spring batch master-slave workflow. In this case if the job is running in multiple instances, I doubt that the job will run in the new instance may also process the records which are already processed. is this correct ? if so how to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find solution? What did you implemented?

Comment: Pls share your experience using AWS Batch. we are looking at implementing similar scenario in our landscape.